# How can I get all start datetime and end datetime of all the months in any year in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Please how do I get the start datetime and end datetime of all the months in a given year in Laravel?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Edit your question with your expected output. Also, show us if you have any code written so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method, If I get your question correctly:

```
public function getStartAndEndOfMonthForGivenYear(int $year): array
{
    $carbon = Carbon::createFromDate($year);
    $currentYear = $carbon->floorYear();
    $data = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
        $data[] = [
            'start' => $currentYear->startOfMonth()->toDateTimeString(),
            'end' => $currentYear->endOfMonth()->toDateTimeString(),
        ];
        $currentYear->startOfMonth()->addMonth();
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$booking = Booking::min('arrival_date')->first();
 
$reservation = Reservation::max('departure_date')->first();
```

Comment: To make your answer complete, please add an explanation